# Django Cities import error

Tags: python, django, importerror, geodjango

I can't get to import data with `manage.py cities --import=all`, I don't have idea of why this is happening. Here is the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 184, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cities/management/commands/cities.py", line 86, in handle
    func()
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cities/management/commands/cities.py", line 312, in import_city
    uptodate = self.download_once('city')
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cities/management/commands/cities.py", line 159, in download_once
    self.download_cache[filekey] = self.download(filekey, i)
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cities/management/commands/cities.py", line 119, in download
    filepath = os.path.join(self.data_dir, filename)
  File "/home/julian/.virtualenvs/duenio/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 75, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

These are the cities settings (I have Postgis installed):

```
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'

...

CITIES_FILES = {
    'city': {
       'filename': ['CO.zip',],
       'urls':     ['http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/'+'{filename}']
    },
}
```

The weird part is, I installed django-cities in a new fresh project, and it did work. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `filenames` instead of `filename` when you provide a list of files:

```
CITIES_FILES = {
    'city': {
       'filenames': ['CO.zip',],
       'urls':     ['http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/'+'{filename}']
    },
}
```

or alternatively:

```
CITIES_FILES = {
    'city': {
       'filename': 'CO.zip',
       'urls':     ['http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/'+'{filename}']
    },
}
```

More details in the Configuration section at https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities

Comment: Man, I thought that was OK and I didn't pay attention to it. It works now, thanks!